# Routing Error uninitialized constant Comments – Making Nested comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, ancestry

I'm learning Rails. I've got an app that has "Ideas", which have "Comments"

I've created the comments using this guide (https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations)

I am using the 'Ancestry' gem to attempt make them nested using this guide on railscasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)

Anyways I'm getting this error "ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Comments):"

This is where I'm getting the error – when I hit the "Reply" link

```
<h3> Comments </h3>

<% @idea.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div> 
        <%= comment.body %>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= link_to "Reply", new_comment_path(:parent_id => comment) %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The above is being rendered on the "Ideas/show.html" page

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @idea.description %>
</p>

<%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @idea} %>
<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @idea} %>

<% if @idea.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_idea_path(@idea) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', ideas_path %>
```

I want to send them here to "Comments/new" which is the same as my form page

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Add a comment here" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :ideas do
    resources :comments, module: :ideas 
  end

  devise_for :users
  root 'ideas#index'
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get "new_comment" => "comments/new"
end
```

Comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!    

    def new
        @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
        @comment.user = current_user
        @comment.save
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comment was posted"
    end

    private    
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Ideas_controller.rb

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_idea, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @ideas = Idea.all

  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @idea = Idea.new
    @idea.comments.build
    respond_with(@idea)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @idea = current_user.ideas.build(idea_params)
    if @idea.save
      redirect_to @idea, notice: "Idea was successfully created."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @idea.update(idea_params)
      redirect_to @idea, notice: "Your idea has been updated"   
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @idea.destroy
    redirect_to ideas_url
  end

  private
    def set_idea
      @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @idea = current_user.ideas.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to ideas_path, notice: "You can't edit this" if @idea.nil?
    end

    def idea_params
      params.require(:idea).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

EDIT _ Added my routes

```
      idea_comments GET    /ideas/:idea_id/comments(.:format)          ideas/comments#index
                         POST   /ideas/:idea_id/comments(.:format)          ideas/comments#create
        new_idea_comment GET    /ideas/:idea_id/comments/new(.:format)      ideas/comments#new
       edit_idea_comment GET    /ideas/:idea_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) ideas/comments#edit
            idea_comment GET    /ideas/:idea_id/comments/:id(.:format)      ideas/comments#show
                         PATCH  /ideas/:idea_id/comments/:id(.:format)      ideas/comments#update
                         PUT    /ideas/:idea_id/comments/:id(.:format)      ideas/comments#update
                         DELETE /ideas/:idea_id/comments/:id(.:format)      ideas/comments#destroy
                   ideas GET    /ideas(.:format)                            ideas#index
                         POST   /ideas(.:format)                            ideas#create
                new_idea GET    /ideas/new(.:format)                        ideas#new
               edit_idea GET    /ideas/:id/edit(.:format)                   ideas#edit
                    idea GET    /ideas/:id(.:format)                        ideas#show
                         PATCH  /ideas/:id(.:format)                        ideas#update
                         PUT    /ideas/:id(.:format)                        ideas#update
                         DELETE /ideas/:id(.:format)                        ideas#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           ideas#index
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                            pages#about
             new_comment GET    /new_comment(.:format)                      comments/new#new_comment
```

Comment: you should have your comments nested into ideas in your config/routes.rb file `resources ideas do resources comments end`, if it's not, then that could be the problem

Comment: Indeed, I have it set up like that and can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: in the ideas_controller you should have something like this in the show action: `def show 
    @comments = @idea.comments
  end
 `. I'm assuming that you are having the error when your are trying to enter in the question show view, let me know how you doing.

Comment: I've added this although it doesn't seem to change much either way. My idea show page shows the comments fine actually, but there's a reply link so that a user can add a subcomment and that's where I'm getting the error. It must have something to do with the routes now that I think about it. I've tried `new_idea_comment_path` as well as `new_comment_path` (which I created in routes on it's own as you can see). Perhaps its because of the way I built the comments without integrating them into the ideas_controller? I've added my routes to the bottom in my question.

Comment: I don't understand something, in the new action for ideas_controller you are loading all the ideas per user, but it should load all the comments for that idea instead, because is a new idea and when you create it you will pass it the user_id of current_user. I think it should be something like this:  `@idea = Idea.new  @idea.comments.build`

Comment: Thanks for the help here. Hmm, yes that seems to make much more sense, I can't remember the reason I had it like that. Although I'm still encountering the same problem having to do with the routes I believe.

Comment: i will recommend this two railscasts http://tinyurl.com/yboun79 and http://tinyurl.com/ybmorw8 and check an excelent gem called cocoon to make nested_forms with ease http://tinyurl.com/3ht2g9h